# java kafka-client can't reconnect after broker restart

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I'm having the same problem with kafka-streams and spring-kafka applications. The first one is using kafka-clients:1.0.0 library while another one version 1.0.2

There is just one broker instance running in kubernetes (KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS="PLAINTEXT://${POD_IP}:9092"). It's stateful set and it's accessed from the client app via headless service internal endpoint (although I've tried cluster ip and the issue is the same)

Once I delete this kafka pod and it's recreated, my client application can't reconnect. Pod is indeed recreated with another ip address but since I'm accessing it via service internal endpoint I'm expecting my client app to resolve this new address but it's not happening.

The kafka-clients library is logging "Found least loaded node [old_ip]:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)" while there is nothing anymore running on this address

JVM TTL cache is not a problem as I've set it to periodically refresh.

Restarting client application solves the problem

If providing {POD_IP} in KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS causes this problem, would providing a pod's hostname solve this problem? Or is there a way to direct my client to resolve this new address?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? It would be helpful to me if you posted a follow up.

Comment: Well, kind of. When java client initially connects to a broker it gets the value stated in KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS and continues using it to connect to broker/s. Since I had {POD_ID} there, it would always be ip address. Once pod gets restarted and changes it's ip address, client can't find it anymore as it continues using previous ip address. My guess is still that providing {POD_HOSTNAME} instead of {POD_IP} would solve the problem but I''ve never validated it so I've never come with a follow up

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it has something to do with  [KAFKA-7755](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7755). Updating client version to  2.2.0 / 2.1.1 should help.